# Custom Arrows react-slick

Tags: carousel, slick.js, react-slick

I am using react-slick to create a carousel in my project.
I've read through the documents and tried different things but could not find a way to customize it exactly the way I need... Does anyone knows if there a way to have the nextArrow show on/in front of the image and not on its right?
See image below for desired result:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLfM4.png)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 28):

I tend to disable the arrows and build them myself.

Create a reference

```
const slider = React.useRef(null);
```

Attach to the slider

```
<Slider ref={slider} {...settings}>
```

Add your buttons wherever you want

```
<button onClick={() => slider?.current?.slickPrev()}>Prev</button>
<button onClick={() => slider?.current?.slickNext()}>Next</button>
```

Comment: Genius! This helped me right away

Comment: I have tried this , but not working

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same problem and have been trying to search for the solutions by following this [CustomArrows documentation](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/custom-arrows/) and some other suggestions but none of them working as what I wanted to (use different icons for the arrow and display the arrow on top of the slides). Then I tried to follow this [previousNextMethods documentation](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/previous-next-methods), and try to adjust it from there.

**index.js**

```
    renderArrows = () => {
    return (
      <div className="slider-arrow">
        <ButtonBase
          className="arrow-btn prev"
          onClick={() => this.slider.slickPrev()}
        >
          <ArrowLeft />
        </ButtonBase>
        <ButtonBase
          className="arrow-btn next"
          onClick={() => this.slider.slickNext()}
        >
          <ArrowRight />
        </ButtonBase>
      </div>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div style={{ position: "relative", marginTop: "2rem" }}>
          {this.renderArrows()}
          <Slider
            ref={c => (this.slider = c)}
            dots={true}
            arrows={false}
            centerMode={true}
            slidesToShow={2}
          >
            <div>
              <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200" alt="cat" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/200" alt="cat" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200" alt="cat" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/200" alt="cat" />
            </div>
          </Slider>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**style.css**

```
.App {
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.slider-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.arrow-btn {
  top: 45%;
}
.next {
  float: right;
}
```

I hope this will help. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-custom-arrows-85ekj)

Answer (score 14):

See official documentation
https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/custom-arrows/
https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/previous-next-methods
Code from there:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

function SampleNextArrow(props) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: "block", background: "red" }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}

function SamplePrevArrow(props) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: "block", background: "green" }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}

export default class CustomArrows extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
      prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Custom Arrows</h2>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

OR

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

export default class PreviousNextMethods extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);
  }
  next() {
    this.slider.slickNext();
  }
  previous() {
    this.slider.slickPrev();
  }
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Previous and Next methods</h2>
        <Slider ref={c => (this.slider = c)} {...settings}>
          <div key={1}>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div key={2}>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div key={3}>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div key={4}>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div key={5}>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div key={6}>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <button className="button" onClick={this.previous}>
            Previous
          </button>
          <button className="button" onClick={this.next}>
            Next
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason first example doesn't work for me - elements not rendered at all when passed through config, going try second one

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way

```
render() {
    const ArrowLeft = (props) => (
        <button
            {...props}
            className={'prev'}/>
    );
    const ArrowRight = (props) => (
        <button
            {...props}
            className={'next'}/>
    );

    const settings = {
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow: <ArrowLeft />,
        nextArrow: <ArrowRight />,
    };

    return (
        <Slider {...settings}>
            {/* items... */}
        </Slider>
    )
}
```

Comment: 's' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: This is a css module usage example. If you are not using the css module, you can give the class name string. @VarinderSohal

Answer (score 0):

If anyone tries to achieve the same result, the way to do it is with some css:

```
.slick-next {
  right: 25px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

function SampleNextArrow(props) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: "block", background: "red" }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}

function SamplePrevArrow(props) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: "block", background: "green" }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}

export default class CustomArrows extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
      prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Custom Arrows</h2>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Check the React-slick Custom Next & Prev buttons here : https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/custom-arrows

Answer (score 0):

Add custom css style

```
.slick-next {
  background: url('./images/next.png') center center no-repeat!important;

  &::before {
    display: none;
  }
}

.slick-prev {
  background: url('./images/back.png') center center no-repeat!important;

  &::before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own arrows and it is mentioned in their documentation like everyone pointed out above.

But if you want to change the images (which mostly would be the case) so what I did was just added 2 lines of code for slider `.slick-next:before & .slick-prev:before`and replaced the content with images. With this you dont need to handle disabling the arrows on last item (which is default). Using the code below just changes your arrows and rest of the behavior remains the same.

**See the code below**

```
.some_class .slick-slider {
    button.slick-next:before {
        content: url("your_image_here.svg");
    }
    button.slick-prev:before {
        content: url("your_image_here.svg");
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that it is required to add onClick prop to your buttons:

```
const SlickArrow = ({onClick}: props) => (
  <button onClick={onClick}><Icon.Arrow /></button>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example replaces the default arrow by another icon

```
import Slider from "react-slick";
import './Example2.css'
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"; 
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa'

function SampleNextArrow(props: any) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      onClick={onClick}
    ><FaBeer style={{ ...style, color: "red", fontSize: "30px" }} /></div>
  );
}

function SamplePrevArrow(props: any) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      onClick={onClick}
    ><FaBeer style={{ ...style, color: "red", fontSize: "30px" }} /></div>
  );
}

const Example2 = () => {
  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
    prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>example 2</h1>
      <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
    </div> 
  );
}
 
export default Example2;
```

and the css

```
.slick-arrow.slick-next:before {
  content: "";
}

.slick-arrow.slick-prev:before {
  content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import prevArrow from './prev-arrow.svg';
import nextArrow from './next-arrow.svg';

const SliderCarousel = () => {
  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    prevArrow: <CustomPrevArrow />,
    nextArrow: <CustomNextArrow />
  };

  return (
    <Slider {...settings}>
      {/* Slides */}
    </Slider>
  );
};

const CustomPrevArrow = (props) => {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, width: '50px', height: '50px', backgroundImage: `url(${prevArrow})`}}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}

const CustomNextArrow = (props) => {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, width: '50px', height: '50px', backgroundImage: `url(${nextArrow})`}}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}

export default SliderCarousel;
```

You can do like this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Many peoples answered this question with different methods. I also came up with mine. Here is my approach where with using only one component we are going to produce both side next and previous arrows and also giving appropriate styling to them.

**LiveScoreArrowsComponent.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

LiveScoreSliderArrow.propTypes = {
  className : PropTypes.string,
  onClick : PropTypes.func,
  style : PropTypes.object,
}
function LiveScoreSliderArrow(props) {
  const {className, style, onClick} = props;
  let arrow_direction = className.search("slick-prev") != -1 ? "left" : "right";
  let class_by_direction = {
    left: className.replace("slick-prev", ""),
    right: className.replace("slick-next", "")
  }

  let hide_flag_class = className.search("slick-disabled") != -1 ? " d-none" : "" 
  return (
    <button style={{...style, top: "unset", lineHeight: "normal"}} className={class_by_direction[arrow_direction] + hide_flag_class + ` p-1 shadow border text-black rounded ri-arrow-${arrow_direction}-s-line ${arrow_direction}`} onClick={onClick}></button>
  )
}

export default LiveScoreSliderArrow
```

**SlickSliderSettings**

```
const SETTINGS = {
  slidesToShow: 3,
  infinite: false,
  swipeToSlide: true,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  variableWidth: true,
  arrows: true,
  nextArrow: <LiveScoreSliderArrow />,
  prevArrow: <LiveScoreSliderArrow />,
}
```

**First make sure to wrap react-slick Slider into an other custom Slider Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-slick'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import Card from '../livescore/card'

LiveScoreSlider.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    settings: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
function LiveScoreSlider({data, settings}) {
  return (
    <Slider className="col-sm-12 d-flex align-items-center livescore-scorecard-container" {...settings}>
        {
                  data.map((livescore, index)=>{
                    // console.log(livescore)
                    return <Card
                      key={index}
                      team1={livescore.teams[0]}
                      team2={livescore.teams[1]}
                      match={livescore.match}
                      stadium={livescore.stadium}
                      series={livescore.series}
                    />
                  })
         }
    </Slider>
  )
}

export default LiveScoreSlider
```

Answer (score -1):

I started with the answer from Oleg above and changed it just a bit to use FontAwesome icons. This method works well to keeps the extra properties from being sent to the FontAwesome components that result in errors such as "React does not recognize the `currentSlide` prop on a DOM element". Thanks to Oleg for the pattern.

```
import React from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

const SomeComponent: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {

  const NextArrow = (props: any) => {
    const { className, style, onClick } = props;
    return (
      <div
        className={className}
        style={{ ...style, display: 'block' }}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-chevron-right" />
      </div>
    );
  };

  const PrevArrow = (props: any) => {
    const { className, style, onClick } = props;
    return (
      <div
        className={className}
        style={{ ...style, display: 'block' }}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-chevron-left" />
      </div>
    );
  };

  const settings = {
    // other settings here ...
    nextArrow: <NextArrow />,
    prevArrow: <PrevArrow />,
    // more settings here ...
  };

  return (
    <Slider {...settings}>
      {/* inner stuff here */}
    </Slider>
  );
};
```